# Parametrization of Cardano triplet

Tags: linear-algebra, project-euler

I'm solving project euler [problem 251](https://projecteuler.net/problem=251). 
I arrived at the conclusion that $$\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt{c}}+ \sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}=1 $$
can be written as $$8a^3+15a^2+6a-27b^2c=1$$
That is really faster to compute for higher numbers than the previous form, but it goes up really fast and I need BigInteger (Java) that slows down again the code.
I found on google that this formula can be parametrized with 
$$a=3k+2$$
and $$b^2c=(k+1)^2(8k+5)$$

I cannot figure out how this parametrization is done. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You have arrived at the conclusion that something that isn't an equation can be written as an equation. You can't mean that – please, edit your question so it says what you actually mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you're right, thank you! I didn't see it. Corrected now

Comment: @Gerry Myerson means that you have forgotten the initial $=1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I noticed this, Then I also miswrote a=3k+2, so I corrected that also, now it seems to be right

Comment: This parameterization looks to come from a consideration of your formula $8a^3+15a^2+6a-27b^2c=1$ **modulo 3*", i.r., $2a^3\equiv1 mod. 3$. Do you know what I mean by "modulo" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your answer. I know what you mean by modulo. But I don't know how to apply it in here

Comment: I explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Explanation of the formula $a=3k+2$ :

Take your big formula modulo 3, i.e.,

$$8a^3+15a^2+6a-27b^2c \equiv 1  \ mod \  3.$$

Because $15, 6$, and $27$ are all multiples of $3$, and $8 \equiv 2 \ mod \ 3$:

$$2a^3 \equiv 1 \ mod \ 3.$$

Let us multiply both sides by 2:

$$4a^3 \equiv 2  \ mod \  3 \ \Longrightarrow \ a^3 \equiv 2  \ mod \  3 \ $$

which has, by inspection of the three cases ($a=0,1,2 \ mod \ 3$)  the unique solution $a \equiv 2  \ mod \  3$.

Thus $a$ is of the form $a=2+3k$ for some integer $k$.

2) Having this expression of $a$, one needs only to expand the RHS of :

$$27b^2c=8a^3+15a^2+6a-1$$

$$=8(2+3k)^3+15(2+3k)^2+6(2+3k)-1$$

finally giving $(k+1)^2(8k+5).$

Comment: Where is the step "take this big formula mod 3" coming from. I can follow what comes next, I can follow the derivation to this step, but why mod 3? Does this also work if we take this modulo $k$ for some $k \neq 3$?

Comment: Because I had observed that three out of four of these coefficients are multiples of 3 , therefore a single term "survives". Any other integer $k$ wouldn't have be so advantageous for the "mod" operation.

Answer (score 0):

$27b^2c=8a^3+15a^2+6a-1=(a+1)(8a^2+7a-1)=(a+1)^2(8a-1)=(3k+3)^2(24k+15)=27(k+1)^2(8k+5)$.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $a=3k+2$ in the equation: $8a^3+15a^2+6a−27b^2c=1$.

We will get $27b^2c=8k^3+21k^2+18k+5$. By observation you can see $k=-1$ is a root of the RHS and then you can transform the equation to a quadratic and then factorize it.